# Windows 10 ISO genuinity

Tags: windows, hashing

I have downloaded Windows 10 and computed the hashes. But I could not find a place including all possible genuine hashes, so I can make sure the ISO is genuine. How can I find if it is indeed genuine?

The hashes are:

sha1: f77830beca3d2ff2f3a6faa3fe14952d5a7706a5

md5: 30d5846cce90f6bf728245d696e1b73f

Filename: Win Pro 10.1511 64BIT EnglishX-82416.ISO

Comment: If you down-loaded it from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO), it is genuine; if you got from anywhere else, you're on your own.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't completely dismiss ISOs not downloaded from Microsoft servers as non-genuine.

Consider this scenario:

I download an ISO from Microsoft servers then save to my PC later I upload it to my cloud services for safe keeping (or perhaps to save HDD space). A friend of mine needs the same ISO and I link them to my cloud drive where they download it. In this case this does not invalidate the genuinity or intergrity of the file.

However I randomly get a link to some cloud drive and download an ISO (no link given by a friend this time) there are 50-50 chances the integrity is compromised or not.

In this case a good way it to compare the hashes. You need a tools to verify file integrity **using MD5 and SHA1 hashes**:

For example:

[IgorWare Hasher](http://www.igorware.com/hasher/download)

[image: a]

Alternatively rather than searching Microsoft’s MSDN pages looking for the correct checksum, it’s easier to use the [Adguard](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/index.php?lang=en-US&extract) (a third party tool to download Windows 7, 8.1 and 10 from Microsoft servers)

Hope this helps

Comment: I have the hashes, but I don't know a place including all possible genuine hashes, so I can compare with.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat: **(1)** OP is asking where he can get the official checksum from. He won’t get it by calculating it from his own copy twice using a different tool each time. **(2)** Your [Adguard solution](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/index.php?lang=en-US&extract) works for me though. The Adguard page delivers correct SHA-1 checksums for each known Windows ISO file. Thanks!